# schedule repeating jobs in Python with time unit specified as a variable

Tags: python, schedule

I've been using the excellent `schedule` library to run a variety of jobs, but there is one thing I can't find.

The Python code for running a job every 10 minutes looks like this:

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
```

Question is: how would I elegantly incorporate the time unit as a variable? I want to do something like this:

```
interval = 3
time_unit = 'hours'
schedule.every(interval).units(time_unit).do(job)
```

to run a job every 3 hours. Using variables would allow the schedule to be configurable.

Except the example above isn't working: the `units` member is a readable value only.

`eval` is not safe in this context.

Comment: What you need exactly ?
Way to parse the yml or anything else.?

Comment: Thanks @Murali, I hope it's clear now

Comment: What is the exception or error you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "`eval` is not safe in this context"? Testing the time_unit value isn't elegant enought?

Comment: Also, lambda can be used !

Comment: Just to clear up what I mean about `eval`. I could write `eval('schedule.every(interval).{units}.do(job)'.format(units=time_unit)` but that is potentially insecure depending on where the time_unit comes from. The eval could be used to call someone else's code by altering something in a config file, for example. http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html is worth a read if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question. Thanks to those who replied.

```
# specify time interval units as a variable in code...
interval = 3
time_unit = 'hours'
schedule.every(interval).set_units(time_unit).do(job)
```

Hotfix in the `schedule` library (class Job)-- add the following method:

```
def set_units(self, unit):
    self.unit = unit if unit[-1] == 's' else unit + 's'
    return self
```

Comment: Not sure how this would fix the problem you are describing.